# How can I modify this switch?

Tags: switches, toggle-switch

Power > toggle > light > extension plug

- When the toggle is ON there is power to the light and power to the extension's plug
- When the toggle is OFF there is no power to the light and no power to the extension's plug

How can I make the light so that it has power when there is NO toggle (no power to the extension's plug) and vice-versa?

[image: power switch]

Comment: You can't, really.  Not in that space and be anywhere close to safe.  With just the light and the switch it can't be done so that it will always work.  If you put the light in parallel to the switch, then it will (usually) light up if something is plugged into the socket.  This puts voltage on the plug even when the switch is off, though.  Not much current because of the neon bulb, but still.  And, if there's nothing plugged into the socket then it won't light.

Comment: To make it always work, you'd need either a switch with more contacts (a second pair that is closed when the main pair is open) or else you need some kind of active circuit.  Neither will fit in that box.

Comment: @JRE Can I take the power side of the light (side which uses the toggle) and connect it to the opposite side to give the light power always? Then the extension's plug is the only thing effect by the toggle, which is fine.

Comment: You could do that.  It would be safe and it would always work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't easily or safely do what you ask.

However, you can make it so the little light shown in your picture is on all the time.  It looks to be just a neon bulb with series resistor.  Those take very little power.  This was a common way to make old night lights, which were basically on all the time.

Think about what the point really is in turning off the light when the switch is on.  Presumably you want the switch to be lighted when off, since the room may then be dark or something.  You don't need the light when the switch is on, but it probably does little harm either.

The additional power is miniscule too.  You already want the light on when the thing being switched is off.  When the thing being switched is on, it likely takes many times more power than the neon light.

Apparently the input power comes in at top right in your picture, and the switched power goes out at bottom left.  If so, move the lower connection of the neon bulb assembly from the left pin of the switch to the right one.